# Alternative task runner to Make that lets you include arbitrary (bash) shell commands?

Tags: make

I am trying to add a step to a make command in a **Makefile**, specifically `alias abc='xyz'` and was shocked to find that it doesn't quite work like that. This is in a go project (learning go).

Is there something like Make that can be used like a task runner with very simple or similar syntax to make but lets you have actual shell commands as steps?
Thanks!